# Subgurim maps control wont render inside a Formview

Tags: asp.net, formview, subgurim-maps

I want to create a subgurim maps control inside a Formview in an asp.net web form page. When I add it to an item template in a formview it wont render. When I place it outside the Formview it renders fine. Is there something I am missing?

Code where it does not render:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="GMaps" Namespace="Subgurim.Controles" TagPrefix="maps" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="main" Runat="Server">
   <div id="content">
       <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <maps:StaticGMap ID="StaticGMap1" runat="server"  format="png32" />
           <maps:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:FormView>    
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Formview has not `DataSourceID` or `DataSource`. If you set a `DataSource` for your FormView You will see the map.